# How can I determine the number and type of metaobjects created?

Tags: java, reflection, metaobject

As far as I've seen, metaobjects are of type: `Type-Info` `Data-Info` and `ObjectCreator`.
In a Java application, how does one determine the number and type of metaobjects created?
Take for instance the following sample code:

```
public class Dtest extends Btest
{
    public int aPublicInt;
    private int aPrivateInt;
    public Dtest(int x)
    {
        // …    
    }

    private void OpD1(String s) {
        // …
    }

    public String OpD2(int x){
        // …
    } 
}
```

Type-info: Dtest object, Class object
Data-Info: Integer object `aPublicInt` , Integer object `aPrivateInt`, void Object `OpD1` , String Object `OpD2`
ObjectCreator Dtest

Is this correct ?

Could anyone also explain to me what connections there are between the metaobjects ?

Comment: Shouldn;t there be any metaobjects created for the base object ? I'm sorry if I get this wrong , can't really wrap my head around this

Comment: What do you mean by "metaobject"? The term isn't in general use in Java (although Groovy uses it).

Comment: an object that manipulates, creates, describes, or implements other objects (including itself). The object that the metaobject is about is called the base object.It's part of reflection